# set radiation foreground title in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, styling, panorama-control

As the title says, I want to set radiation effect for my panorama title, or panorama item title. (An example would be music+video app in windows phone 7) How can I do this? The set of foreground only let me choose solid brush color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider learning how to use Expression Blend, as it's much easier for such problems.

But regardless of that, any brush can be created on-the-fly, if you do a verbose-binding in XAML. You can read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx)

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World">
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.75,0.25">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```